# Convert byte to bool in C#

Tags: c#, arduino, rfid, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying make a library to iot core on c# based on arduino library (http://blog.electrodragon.com/rc522-write-a-card-demo-code/) but i don't understand what is:

```
if (!(temp & 0x03))
```

or

```
while ((i!=0) && !(n&0x01) && !(n&waitIRq))
```

It's required boolean values but those are bytes!
How i can convert this?

If anyone know a library already made, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have you tried using Convert.ToBoolean()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C any non-zero expression is implicitly true, and zero is false. In C# you need to do an explicit comparison:

```
if ((temp & 0x03) == 0)
```

and

```
while ((i!=0) && (n&0x01)==0 && (n&waitIRq)==0)
```

Alternatively, you can use [the .NET's Boolean structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool isTempAppropriate = (temp & 0x03) == 0;
if(isTempAppropriate) { ... }
```

Note that `bool` is just syntactic sugar for `System.Boolean`, and that you could have used [the `var` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) instead of `bool`.

Comment: Also here is too much brackets for C# :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `!(n&0x01)` in C is `(n&0x01) == 0` in C#.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Very true, fixed! Thank you very much!!